# iOS: Alert-View with RTF (Bold, URLs etc)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uialertview, rtf, alert

I need to display a message to the user.

However, it is quite a long message.   Really to be clear I need to split it into paragraphs and use Bold for headings.   Also I need to supply a web link for 'more information'.

What is my best solution path?

All I can think of at the moment is to create an analogue of a UIAlertView that uses a UIWebView + a UIButton

And the web view loads an RTF file from the bundle.

If I create this inside a full-screen view set to 50% Alpha,  it will fade out whatever window is behind...  but I would rather not code up my own component if there is something already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Create a UIViewController with a UIView, UIWebView and UIButton(s) to present the transparent view. You may be able to use UIPopoverController.

The web view content will need to also set a transparent background.